# Cannot seem to get proxy working in Node Express and React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-proxy-middleware

I am completely revising this post in light of new information.

The basic problem is this: I am writing a MERN stack app, serving files from the Node side with a React user interface. The Node server is running on localhost:5000. The react front end is running on localhost:3000. I need to proxy between them. I am using http-proxy-middleware to create the proxy and I can see that the proxy is being created. However, my axios commands are failing with server errors (500). I have been able to trace the specific axios commands that are failing. I can't figure out why. Some screen shots that will show you  what is going on are shown below. And here is a link to the repo if that helps. The lines that are failing are 33 and 66 of the last screen shot.

https://github.com/dhawkinson/TH12-BnBConcierge

I will appreciate any help that is forthcoming.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: glancing at your code. `routes/api/auth` does not export your router. notice how the other files have `module.exports = router` but the broken one doesn't

Comment: @azium Thank you for the observation. It is humbling to think that I have looked at this for days and not noticed that very significant oversight. However I am still getting the message: xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: what's the server this time?

Comment: @azium - I'm not following your question.

Comment: oh eorry, i missed the word "error" what's the server error this time (you said there's a 500, what's the corresponding error on the terminal?)

Comment: @azium: had a family emergency, been away a couple of day, no worries though everything is OK now. However, I have also been through my code syncing things up between the server side and the client side. Now I'm not getting the errors regarding the proxy. It is simply failing silently to write data to my collection. Looking into that now.

Comment: np! feel free to join our slack group https://torontojs.com/ (link in the corner) we have a very good #help channel that's better for problems that can't be answered in single form